# Is there an example of how to customize a .NET 4.0 profiler?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, profiling, clr4.0

I know there is one for profiler 2.0: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx
But the profiler API has changed in .NET 4.0 and we need to consider in-process side by side issues. I need an example to customize our own profiler. Anyone knows that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an actual example, but [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2010/08/25/profilers-in-process-side-by-side-clr-instances-and-a-free-test-harness.aspx) is exactly about your question. Also check out the rest of his blog, there are more posts about 4.0 profilers (and profilers in general).

By the way, in the comments section of the linked blog post he says the official 4.0 profiler source is not ready, but when it is he'll post about it. (Though this was 4 months ago or something.)

**Edit:** [CLRProfiler 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx) just got released and includes source code, so you got your sample ;-)